# How to calculate a score when you drag and drop information from a textbox into multiple DrapDrop event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a simple game application in windows forms.  You can drag the information from a textbox and drop it into a Dragdrop event from one MDI application to another.  This is all OK but the problem I am having is that I have multiple DragDrop events and I am trying to calculate the score for all of them.

What I have tried so far is this.

```
public void score(int calcScore)
{
    lblScore.Text += calcScore.ToString();
}

private void square_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if(shape.Contains("Square"))
    {
        int calcScore = 0;
        calcScore++;
        score(calcScore);
    }
}    

private void circle_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if(shape.Contains("Circle"))
    {
        int calcScore = 0;
        calcScore++;
        score(calcScore);
    }
}
```

The problem is that this will add the to score together as a string so the result will be 11 instead of 2.

If I try this:

```
public void score(int calcScore)
{
    int totalScore =0;
    totalScore = totalScore + calcScore;
    lblScore.Text += totalScore.ToString();
}
```

The problem with this is that once I initialize the totalScore it sets the total score back to 0 so the totalScore will always be 1.

How can I get the score properly calculated like this?

Comment: Strings are not numbers.  You need to convert your strings into numbers.  Use the [Int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method.  `lblScore.Text += ...` will only concatenate the string, it won't do the arithmetic.  Try `lblScore.Text = yourNumber.ToString();`

Comment: @LarsTech no, it doesn't work as it that just keeps the score as 1 and doesn't add to the value

Comment: You are always _setting_ it to one:   `int calcScore = 0; calcScore++; score(calcScore); `  Get the score from the label, convert it to int, then add to it and put it back.   Or keep a class member of int that is the score.

Comment: Move your declarations `int totalScore` to the form level.  Your `calcScore` is confusing because you are declaring it and using it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
public void score(int calcScore)
{
    lblScore.Text += calcScore.ToString();
}
```

This does a cocatenation of the strings. So:

```
"1" + "1" = "11";
```

Just as

```
"cat"+"cat" = "catcat";
```

2.

Initialise

```
int totalScore =0; 
int calcScore =0;
```

at a class level. Every time you use your DragDrop or method `score(int calcScore)` you are resetting these values to zero.